# Does somebody know how to fix "[emerg] 149#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)" problem on Heroku using nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, heroku

I was making a new website to post it to Heroku, and I added a very barebones nginx.conf file to the mix on my Procfile.
When posting and loading up the page, I got a 503 error. Looking at my logs, it said "[emerg] 149#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)".

This is my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
#worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


#events {
#    worker_connections  1024;
#}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

But the thing is, something **really** bizarre happened. On yet another website I had, I used this nginx.conf file...

```
http {
    error_page 404 /app/error404.html;
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /app;
        }
    }
}
```

...and it worked. I do not know what in the world may be causing this. Does somebody know?

Comment: You don't get to pick the port you listen on with Heroku. Why are you trying to write your own Nginx config file in the first place? Do you have unusual needs? The official PHP buildpack ships with Nginx support via an awkward config file that gets pre-processed by PHP. I strongly urge you to just use that config if you can.

Comment: I want to specify custom error pages. I just switched server from Apache to NGINX, since httpd.conf is too cumbersome. I just want a custom error page and CORS support.